# Memory upgrade for 27" iMac, mid 2011

Tags: imac

I recently upgraded the memory in my 27" iMac, mid 2011.  took out the two, 2 gig in the top slots & put in two 8 gig units.  For some reason I wasn't thinking about putting the 2 gig units in the bottom slots.  Is this ok? Will it help any?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It will likely work, however many people will advice you to only use matching sticks of RAM.  In other words, if you're going to use 4 sticks, ensure they are all of the speed, capacity, brand, etc.

You wouldn't build a RAID array with mismatched drive manufacturers, speeds, and capacities, why do it with your RAM?

Comment: Actually, neither capacity nor brand are important, if speed, ECC etc all match & each *pair* are truly identical. My machine runs perfectly happily on a pair of 1s, a pair of 4s, & a pair of 8s, giving the odd total of 26GB RAM.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I think I will install them & see how it goes.